# It totally works for me!

Tags: word-usage, word-order

In a situation when I talk with someone about setting up a schedule, can we use "totally" with a phrase like the title?
I know that the meaning of *totally* itself is basically used for emphasizing the expression. And I also know that *completely* sounds more polite and also a little old.　But what I just want to know is whether native speakers use "totally" in this kind of situation or not.
Does it sound normal? Or do you have some other better suggestions?

Comment: Yes, lots of native speakers us it this way. The question is whether you want to choose those speakers to emulate or not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valleyspeak

Comment: Hello Noriakienglish! By the way, In the UK we say 'talk to', not 'talk with'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Really? Here in the rebellious colonies, *talk to* and *talk with* are broadly interchangeable, but: “Did Bob talk with you?” “Well, he talked *to* me,” implying he was not interested in listening.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood It doesn't imply that here.

Comment: All I have to say about this is, [gag me with a spoon](https://genius.com/Frank-zappa-valley-girl-lyrics).

Answer (score 1):

It totally works for me.  I'm totally into it.  Or I'm way into it.  These are fine for conversation.  But for formal writing, I'd use "quite".  "I'm quite used to it.  "It quite works for me."  "Indeed" is nice to use formally. "It works indeed for me."  Or "It indeed works for me."  Or, more naturally, "It works well for me." (You know better than to say, "It works *good* for me,") If you want to convey degree, then "completely works," as suggested, is good.

Comment: Thank you! Those phrases helped me a lot! Some of them were new for me. I'm going to use "It quite works for me" which sounds more polite. With it, I can be a more gentleman than now:)

Comment: @Noriakienglish — Totally wrong decision. (Like the last sentence.) It either works or it doesn’t, so “quite works” is contradictory and sounds wrong. If you wish to add emphasis you can use “certainly works”. This asserts the truth of the statement, not the extent of the condition. But you should be on ELL, not here.